# Appium not able to identify and scroll element on android device

Tags: android, mobile, automation, appium

I am trying a piece of appium automation code on the clock app in android but my code tends to skip the scrolling logic. I also tried to findelement() and gettext() to identify the element but still unsuccessful. Following is the code:

```
package com.test.Clock; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver; 
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement; 
import io.appium.java_client.PerformsTouchActions; 
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction; 
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
import java.net.URL; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension; 
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor; 
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException; 
import org.openqa.selenium.Point; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions; 
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities; 
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait; 
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass; 

public class Clock { 

static WebDriver driver; 
//static AndroidDriver driver; 

@BeforeClass public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{ DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android"); capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "7.0"); capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV"); capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android"); capabilities.setCapability("--session-override",true); capabilities.setCapability("noReset",true); capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.deskclock"); capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock"); //driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities); 
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
} 

@Test public void testCal() throws InterruptedException { System.out.println("inside test"); 
WebElement createAlarm=driver.findElement(By.id("amigo:id/amigo_icon0")); //WebElement createAlarm=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Create']")); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); createAlarm.click(); 
// WebElement plus=driver.findElement(By.id("amigo:id/amigo_numberpicker_input")); //plus.click(); 
// driver.swipe(6, -188, 0, 0, 2); 
try { 
WebElement frame1=driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber")); 
driver.switchTo().frame(frame1);
} 
catch (NoSuchFrameException e) { 
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} 
Thread.sleep(2000); 
WebElement gettime=driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber")); 
Thread.sleep(2000); 
System.out.println(gettime.getText()); 
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>(); System.out.println(swipeObject); 
swipeObject.put("startX", 3.0); 
System.out.println(swipeObject); 
swipeObject.put("startY", -183.8); 
System.out.println(swipeObject); 
swipeObject.put("endX", 0.022); 
System.out.println(swipeObject); 
swipeObject.put("endY", 0.02); 
System.out.println(swipeObject); 
swipeObject.put("duration", 2.0); 
//HashMap[] params = { swipeObject }; 
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", swipeObject); 
System.out.println(js); 
/*JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>(); scrollObject.put("direction", "up"); 
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);*/ 
Thread.sleep(2000); 
WebElement equalTo=driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_save")); equalTo.click(); 
} 
@AfterClass public void teardown(){ 
//close the app driver.quit();
}
}
```

and following is appium server log:

> Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args:
>   [{"--session-override":true,"BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"7.0","appActivity":"com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock","appPackage":"com.android.deskclock","deviceName":"IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV","noReset":true,"platformName":"Android"},null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"--session-override":true,"BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"7.0","appActivity":"com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock","appPackage":"com.android.deskclock","deviceName":"IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV","noReset":true,"platformName":"Android"},"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"android"}]}]
>   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1528276642225
>   (14:47:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) [Appium] Could not parse W3C
>   capabilities: 'deviceName' can't be blank. Falling back to JSONWP
>   protocol. [Appium] The following capabilities were provided in the
>   JSONWP desired capabilities that are missing in W3C capabilities:
>   ["--session-override","BROWSER_NAME","VERSION","appActivity","appPackage","deviceName","noReset","platformName"].
>   Falling back to JSONWP protocol. [Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver
>   (v2.6.0) session [Appium] Capabilities: [Appium] --session-override:
>   true [Appium] BROWSER_NAME: Android [Appium] VERSION: 7.0 [Appium]
>   appActivity: com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock [Appium] appPackage:
>   com.android.deskclock [Appium] deviceName: IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV [Appium]
>   noReset: true [Appium] platformName: Android [BaseDriver] Creating
>   session with MJSONWP desired capabilities:
>   {"--session-override":true,... [BaseDriver] The following capabilities
>   were provided, but are not recognized by appium: --session-override,
>   BROWSER_NAME, VERSION. [BaseDriver] Session created with session id:
>   7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba [AndroidDriver] Getting Java
>   version [AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_101 [ADB] Checking
>   whether adb is present [ADB] Using adb.exe from
>   C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   [AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list [ADB] Trying to find a
>   connected android device [ADB] Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1
>   device(s) connected [AndroidDriver] Using device: IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV
>   [ADB] Checking whether adb is present [ADB] Using adb.exe from
>   C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe [ADB]
>   Setting device id to IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV [AndroidDriver] App file was not
>   listed, instead we're going to run com.android.deskclock directly on
>   the device [AndroidDriver] Checking whether package is present on the
>   device [ADB] Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
>   [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell pm list packages com.android.deskclock'
>   [AndroidDriver] Starting Android session [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV wait-for-device' [ADB] Getting connected
>   devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell echo ping' [AndroidDriver] Pushing
>   settings apk to device... [ADB] Getting install status for
>   io.appium.settings [ADB] Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1
>   device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell pm list packages io.appium.settings'
>   [ADB] App is installed [ADB] Getting package info for
>   'io.appium.settings' [ADB] Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1
>   device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
>   [ADB] Checking whether aapt is present [ADB] Using aapt.exe from
>   C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.0-rc2\aapt.exe
>   [ADB] The installed 'io.appium.settings' package does not require
>   upgrade ('2.3.0' >= '2.3.0') [ADB] Getting connected devices... [ADB]
>   1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell ps' [AndroidDriver] io.appium.settings
>   is already running. There is no need to reset its permissions. [ADB]
>   Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' [ADB]
>   Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 24 [ADB] Device API
>   level: 24 [ADB] Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s)
>   connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell appops set io.appium.settings
>   android:mock_location allow' [AndroidDriver] setDeviceLanguageCountry
>   requires language or country. [AndroidDriver] Got language:
>   'undefined' and country: 'undefined' [Logcat] Starting logcat capture
>   [AndroidDriver] Pushing unlock helper app to device... [ADB] Getting
>   install status for io.appium.unlock [ADB] Getting connected devices...
>   [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell pm list packages io.appium.unlock'
>   [ADB] App is installed [ADB] Getting package info for
>   'io.appium.unlock' [ADB] Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1
>   device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell dumpsys package io.appium.unlock' [ADB]
>   Checking whether aapt is present [ADB] Using aapt.exe from
>   C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.0-rc2\aapt.exe
>   [ADB] The installed 'io.appium.unlock' package does not require
>   upgrade ('2.0.0' >= '2.0.0') [ADB] Getting device platform version
>   [ADB] Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB]
>   Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell getprop ro.build.version.release' [ADB]
>   Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 7.0 [ADB] Getting
>   connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell wm size' [ADB] Getting connected
>   devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell getprop ro.product.model' [ADB] Current
>   device property 'ro.product.model': S6s [ADB] Getting connected
>   devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer' [ADB]
>   Current device property 'ro.product.manufacturer': GIONEE
>   [AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
>   [AndroidDriver] No app capability. Assuming it is already on the
>   device [AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect [ADB]
>   Forwarding system: 4724 to device: 4724 [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724' [UiAutomator]
>   Starting UiAutomator [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'starting'
>   [UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar [UiAutomator] Found jar name:
>   'AppiumBootstrap.jar' [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV push 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-android-bootstrap\bootstrap\bin\AppiumBootstrap.jar'
>   /data/local/tmp/' [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
>   [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator [ADB] Getting connected
>   devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell ps' [ADB] No uiautomator process found
>   to kill, continuing... [UiAutomator] Starting UIAutomator [ADB]
>   Creating ADB subprocess with args:
>   ["-P",5037,"-s","IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","com.android.deskclock","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
>   [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online' [AndroidBootstrap] Android
>   bootstrap socket is now connected [ADB] Getting connected devices...
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected [ADB] 1
>   device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell dumpsys window' [AndroidDriver] Screen
>   already unlocked, doing nothing [ADB] Device API level: 24 [ADB]
>   Getting connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell am start -W -n
>   com.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock -S' [Appium]
>   New AndroidDriver session created successfully, session
>   7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba added to master session list
>   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1528276661138
>   (14:47:41 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) [W3C] Responding to client
>   with driver.createSession() result:
>   {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"--session-override":true,"BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"7.0","appActivity":"com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock","appPackage":"com.android.deskclock","deviceName":"IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV","noReset":true,"platformName":"Android"},"--session-override":true,"BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"7.0","appActivity":"com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock","appPackage":"com.android.deskclock","deviceName":"IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV","noReset":true,"platformName":"Android","deviceUDID":"IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV","platformVersion":"7.0","deviceScreenSize":"1080x1920","deviceModel":"S6s","deviceManufacturer":"GIONEE"}
>   [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 18916 ms - 866 [HTTP] [HTTP] -->
>   POST /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/timeouts
>   [HTTP] {"type":"implicit","ms":15000} [W3C] Bad parameters:
>   BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted "W3C protocol
>   expects any of script, pageLoad or implicit to be set" and you sent
>   {"type":"implicit","ms":15000} [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/timeouts 400 3 ms
>   - 5166 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element [HTTP]
>   {"using":"id","value":"amigo:id/amigo_icon0"} [W3C] Calling
>   AppiumDriver.findElement() with args:
>   ["id","amigo:id/amigo_icon0","7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"]
>   [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id,
>   class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator [BaseDriver]
>   Waiting up to 0 ms for condition [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to
>   android:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"amigo:id/amigo_icon0","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"amigo:id/amigo_icon0","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding
>   'amigo:id/amigo_icon0' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple:
>   false [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using:
>   UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=amigo:id/amigo_icon0]
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"}} [AndroidBootstrap] Received
>   command result from bootstrap [W3C] Responding to client with
>   driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"1"} [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element 200 1496
>   ms - 87 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/timeouts [HTTP]
>   {"type":"implicit","ms":3000} [W3C] Bad parameters:
>   BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted "W3C protocol
>   expects any of script, pageLoad or implicit to be set" and you sent
>   {"type":"implicit","ms":3000} [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/timeouts 400 2 ms
>   - 5164 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element/1/click
>   [HTTP] {"id":"1"} [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args:
>   ["1","7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"] [AndroidBootstrap]
>   Sending command to android:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"1"}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"1"}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: click
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result:
>   {"status":0,"value":true} [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result
>   from bootstrap [W3C] Responding to client with driver.click() result:
>   true [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element/1/click
>   200 350 ms - 76 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element [HTTP]
>   {"using":"id","value":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber"}
>   [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args:
>   ["id","com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber","7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"]
>   [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id,
>   class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator [BaseDriver]
>   Waiting up to 0 ms for condition [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to
>   android:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding
>   'com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber' using 'ID'
>   with the contextId: '' multiple: false [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP
>   LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0,
>   RESOURCE_ID=com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber]
>   [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap [W3C]
>   Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"2"}
>   [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element 200 1884
>   ms - 87 [HTTP] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning
>   result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"}} [HTTP] --> POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/frame [HTTP]
>   {"id":{"ELEMENT":"2","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"2"}} [W3C]
>   Calling AppiumDriver.setFrame() with args:
>   [{"ELEMENT":"2","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"2"},"7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"]
>   [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/frame 404 2 ms -
>   3078 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element [HTTP]
>   {"using":"id","value":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber"}
>   [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args:
>   ["id","com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber","7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"]
>   [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id,
>   class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator [BaseDriver]
>   Waiting up to 0 ms for condition [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to
>   android:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding
>   'com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber' using 'ID'
>   with the contextId: '' multiple: false [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP
>   LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0,
>   RESOURCE_ID=com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_activity_hourNumber]
>   [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap [W3C]
>   Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"3"}
>   [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element 200 21 ms
>   - 87 [HTTP] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"}} [HTTP] --> GET
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element/3/text
>   [HTTP] {} [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.getText() with args:
>   ["3","7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"] [AndroidBootstrap]
>   Sending command to android:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getText","params":{"elementId":"3"}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getText","params":{"elementId":"3"}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: getText
>   [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap [W3C]
>   Responding to client with driver.getText() result: "" [HTTP] <-- GET
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element/3/text
>   200 24 ms - 74 [HTTP] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug]
>   Returning result: {"status":0,"value":""} [HTTP] --> POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/execute [HTTP]
>   {"script":"mobile:
>   scroll","args":[{"duration":2,"endY":0.02,"endX":0.022,"startY":-183.8,"startX":3}]}
>   [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.execute() with args: ["mobile:
>   scroll",[{"duration":2,"endY":0.02,"endX":0.022,"startY":-183.8,"startX":3}],"7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"]
>   [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/execute 404 4 ms
>   - 5796 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element [HTTP]
>   {"using":"id","value":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_save"} [W3C]
>   Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args:
>   ["id","com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_save","7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"]
>   [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id,
>   class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator [BaseDriver]
>   Waiting up to 0 ms for condition [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to
>   android:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_save","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_save","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding
>   'com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_save' using 'ID' with the
>   contextId: '' multiple: false [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG]
>   [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0,
>   RESOURCE_ID=com.android.deskclock:id/add_alarm_save]
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"}} [AndroidBootstrap] Received
>   command result from bootstrap [W3C] Responding to client with
>   driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"4"} [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element 200 28 ms
>   - 87 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element/4/click
>   [HTTP] {"id":"4"} [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.click() with args:
>   ["4","7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"] [AndroidBootstrap]
>   Sending command to android:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"4"}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"4"}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: click
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result:
>   {"status":0,"value":true} [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result
>   from bootstrap [W3C] Responding to client with driver.click() result:
>   true [HTTP] <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba/element/4/click
>   200 355 ms - 76 [HTTP] [HTTP] --> DELETE
>   /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba [HTTP] {} [W3C]
>   Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args:
>   ["7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba"] [BaseDriver] Event
>   'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1528276671521 (14:47:51 GMT+0530
>   (India Standard Time)) [Appium] Removing session
>   7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba from our master session list
>   [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver [ADB] Getting connected
>   devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell am force-stop com.android.deskclock'
>   [ADB] Pressing the HOME button [ADB] Getting connected devices...
>   [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell input keyevent 3' [AndroidBootstrap]
>   Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"} [AndroidBootstrap]
>   [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
>   [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator [UiAutomator] Moving to state
>   'stopping' [UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally [UiAutomator]
>   Moving to state 'stopped' [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator
>   processes [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator [ADB] Getting
>   connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users\PAKALI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P
>   5037 -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell ps' [ADB] No uiautomator process found
>   to kill, continuing... [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
>   [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture [ADB] Getting connected devices...
>   [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [ADB] Running
>   'C:\Users{Username[![screenshot for
>   app][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id3Ly.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id3Ly.jpg)}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037
>   -s IFZDSCVCKJUWRSOV shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock' [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles`
>   capability if wanted. [BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionFinished' logged
>   at 1528276676716 (14:47:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) [W3C]
>   Received response: null [W3C] But deleting session, so not returning
>   [W3C] Responding to client with driver.deleteSession() result: null
>   [HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/7118f268-78fb-4b3e-91fa-f46f119d6dba
>
> ### 200 5196 ms - 76

Comment: pardon me for my formatting skills.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong library to perform that action, the js.execute("mobile: scroll") is for iOS. You need to look into the TouchAction library. Here is a link to their documentation http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

Comment: Have tried swipe() which takes only integer arguments (technically it should accept double).
swipe() only supports if we use AndroidDriver and not WebDriver.
If we use AndroidDriver then the other selenium code like  .click() or .sendKeys() are getting skipped.
And even swipe() not getting executed properly.
If we use WebDriver then the code does not support the swipe() function.
So, if we want other selenium code to work properly we have to take WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with scrolling on an android device via Appium as well.
In my case the main problem was that the scroll action was performed before the fragment I wanted to scroll in was ready.

## Scenario:

click button to open new fragment -> scroll from y 500 to y 100

## Solution:

click button to open new fragment -> wait for a element A of the opened fragment -> scroll from y 500 to y 100 after the element A was found

## Code for scrolling(Kotlin):

```
//wait for some element of the fragment before, then scroll:
PlatformTouchAction(driver as AppiumDriver)
            .press(PointOption.point(100,500))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(200)))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(100,100)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
            .release()
            .perform()
```

The PlatfromTouchAction is just a wrapper to make TouchAction usable in Kotlin like described [in this discussion](https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-use-touchaction-in-kotlin/22567)